# Different time ranges in Grafana 9.5 with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time, overriding, grafana, datetimerangefield

there! I have a dashboard with different visualizations in Grafana 9. I used Postgresql to get the data from a database that has a column for time and I want 3 visualizations with different time ranges, but they still change based on the time settings.

I have tried changing the Query Options (relative time), and tried creating an override. But it is still not working. Does anyone know how I can solve this? Thank you so much in advance! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.